# double operation precision issue

Tags: java

I faced similar issue in javascript which i resolved by multiplying and divinding by 1000. How can I resolve this in Java?

Code snippet:

```
double a=Double.parseDouble("1.8")/100;
System.out.println(a);
```

Output:

```
0.018000000000000002
```

I want 0.018 as output. Suggestions?

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` or round accordingly. Calculations with double will eventually result in precision issues.

Comment: double has been used extensively.I can't change it everywhere.any work around other than rounding?

Comment: You can't change it, or you just don't want to?

Comment: it will be a huge change.so i am avoiding it.

Comment: Are you concerned with the output only? i.e. removing the `000000000000002`

Comment: its like i am not sure whether i may need 4 digit precision or in some cases 3 digit precision.it can vary.

Comment: You can use `BigDecimal` for calculations and convert to and from double but you might still get precision issues if the number can't be represented accurately. Thus some form of rounding might still be necessary.

Comment: thanks for the valuable comments.I try what i can do with minimal changes in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
 double a=Double.parseDouble("1.8")/100;
      DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.000");
      String f = df.format(a); 
      try {
        double dblValue = (Double)df.parse(f) ;
        System.out.println(dblValue);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

or

```
      double dblValue2 = Math.round( a * 1000.0 ) / 1000.0;
      System.out.println(dblValue2);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need great precision, it's better to stick to BigDecimal instead of using Double.

BigDecimal can hold arbitrary precision and size numbers, while Double has a limited precision due to its representation.

The downside is that BigDecimal has worse preformance, and that code writing is more verbose (BigDecimal cannot use '+', '-', etc. operators).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to increase prevision, or to do pretty printing?
If you want to print 0.018 you can use

```
System.out.printf("%.3f%n",a);
```

%.3f means print a floating number with 3 digits after '.'

%n means new line

You can look on [this german site](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel9/javainsel_04_010.htm#mj858fbf1c224f5da2028e472edf93dba4) how to use printf. Just scroll down for listing 4.30 (you don't need to understand german to understand the example)